# Why does jQuery post my form twice?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to post a form depending on which button was pressed. 
I can see in the firebug console that the  form is getting posted twice. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myForm").submit( function(e) { //If add btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var url = "process_ajax4.php";

    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    formdata += "&btn=btn_add"; // added the btn
    $.post(url, formdata,
        function(data) {

            $("#results").html(data); //Response

        });
});

$("#myForm").submit( function(e) { //If add btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var url = "process_ajax4.php";

    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    formdata += "&btn=btn_remove"; // added the btn
    $.post(url, formdata,
        function(data) {

            $("#results").html(data); //Response
        });
  });

});
```

The Form

```
<td>
    <form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="\" method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=". $collab_userid." />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value=".$upload_id." />

        <button  type="submit" id="btn_remove" class="btn_remove" name= "btn_remove">Remove</button>
        <button  id="btn_add" class= "btn_add" name="btn_add">Approve</button>
    </form>
</td>
```

Comment: Why do you have two submit handlers?

Comment: The two `$("#myForm").submit` is the cause of the bug.

Comment: @Ali7091 Although it's good practice to do that in many situations, in this case it will make no difference because the code `e.preventDefault()` is already preventing the default submit action. The duplicate event handlers is the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Because you have 2 submit event listeners and no condition to check which button was  submitted in your form.

I suggest changing to one submit event listener (to ensure only one AJAX request will be fired, and reduce code duplication) and then add a condition to check which button was submitted.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myForm").submit( function(e) { //If add btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var url = "process_ajax4.php";

    // Get the button name
    var button =  $(this).find("button[clicked=true]").attr('name'); 

    var formdata = $(this).serialize();

    switch(button){
       case "btn_add":
          formdata += "&btn=btn_add"; 
          break;
       case "btn_remove":
          formdata += "&btn=btn_remove"; 
          break;
    }

    $.post(url, formdata,
        function(data) {

            $("#results").html(data); //Response

        });
});
```

Comment: where is `button` being declared in this example?

Comment: @ADyson It isn't... This is just an example of the logic required, not a full working solution.

Comment: I understand this,thanks but can't seem to figure how to declare the button.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have two submit handlers and both do the same thing

Demo : http://jsbin.com/luvenaxela/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#myForm button[type=button]").on('click',function(e) { //If  btn pressed
    e.preventDefault();

    var type = $(this).attr('name');

    if( type == 'btn_remove'){

         // Action on Remove button 

    }else if( type == 'btn_add'){

        // Action  on add button 

    }

    });
});
```

Try this